# Prebuilt UI for peer-to-peer chat?

Tags: chat, p2p

I need to add a peer-to-peer live chat function to my website. I'd like to use a prebuilt UI that can integrate into my current website. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with React, you can use https://github.com/chatscope/chat-ui-kit-react for UI together with https://github.com/chatscope/use-chat for connecting UI with your P2P communication layer.

It's not exactly prebuilt UI, but based on [documentation](https://chatscope.io/storybook/react/?path=/story/documentation-introduction--page) you can make the chat UI very fast.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of both tools.

Comment: Oh cool! Thanks for sending that over. Would you be open to chatting quickly about this so I can get a better idea?

Comment: Sure, feel free to chat with me

Comment: I'm not able to create a chatroom. Do you have Linkedin? Here is mine: https://www.linkedin.com/in/matt-mccoy/